# React navigation through sections with anchor elements doesn't work in mobile views

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to navigate through sections in the same page of a React application setting ids in section elements and with anchor elements . It works fine when the viewport is the desktop browser, but when viewport is switched to some mobile it doesn't work.

My application in mobile view contains a sidebar with the navigation sections that shows or hide with an hamburguer menu. In desktop version the sidebar is always show.

The application doesn't contain other "pages" it's just sections on the same page. Is there any solution to this problem?

This portion of code contains the sections of the page, I have a context that stores the refs of those sections (only shown two for test).

```
export const MainContent = () => {
  const scrollNavContext = useContext(ScrollNavContext);
  const aboutMeRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const portfolioRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if(aboutMeRef && aboutMeRef.current) {
      scrollNavContext.pushSection?.({
        name: aboutMeRef.current?.id,
        refObj: aboutMeRef,
      })
    }

    if(portfolioRef && portfolioRef.current) {
      scrollNavContext.pushSection?.({
        name: portfolioRef.current?.id,
        refObj: portfolioRef,
      });
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [aboutMeRef, portfolioRef]);  

  return (
      <div
        id="Content"
        className={clsx(
          'mt-[54px]',
          'md:mt-0',
          'relative',
          'overflow-x-hidden'
        )}
      >
        <CandyBackground />

        <div className={clsx('relative', 'z-20')}>
          <section ref={aboutMeRef} id="aboutme">
            <AboutMe />
          </section>
          <section id="experience">
            <Experience />
          </section>
          <section id="skills">
            <Skills />
          </section>
          <section ref={portfolioRef} id="portfolio">Portfolio</section>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

The NavItem component handles the scroll into view with the context

```
export const NavItem: React.FC<INavItemProps> = ({ text, icon, url, onClick}) => {

  const scrollNavContext = useContext(ScrollNavContext);
  
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    console.log(" ~ file: NavItem.tsx:18 ~ handleOnClick ~:", url);
    
    scrollNavContext.navigate(url || '');
    onClick?.();
  }

  return (
    // <div className="flex items-center py-2 pl-6 gap-3 w-full hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-m_gold hover:to-m_orange hover:cursor-pointer hover:transition-colors duration-1000">
  
      <div
        className={clsx('...')}
        onClick={handleOnClick}
      >
        <span className="text-slate-100 text-center text-lg w-5 h-5 md:w-8 md:h-8">{icon}</span>
        <Typography className={{size: 'text-md md:text-lg', color: 'text-slate-100'}} text={text} />
      </div>
    
  );
};
```

And the ScrollNavContextProvider manages the "goto" section with the refs.

```
export const ScrollNavContextProvider: React.FC<{
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState<IScrollNavSection[]>([]);

  const pushSection = (s: IScrollNavSection) => {
    console.log(' ~ file: NavContext.tsx:26 ~ pushSection ~ s:', s);
    if (! sections.find((i) => i.name === s.name)) {
      setSections((prev) => {
        return [...prev, s];
      });
    }
  };

  const navigate = (section: string) => {
    console.log(' ~ file: NavContext.tsx:34 ~ navigate ~ section:', section);
    const s = sections.find((a) => a.name === section);
    console.log(" ~ file: NavContext.tsx:44 ~ navigate ~ s:", s)
    
    if (s && s.refObj.current) {
    
      s.refObj.current?.scrollIntoView();
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollNavContext.Provider
      value={{ sections, pushSection, navigate }}
    >
      {children}
    </ScrollNavContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

As I mentioned before, this works fine when the browser view is on desktop mode, but when is mobile doesn't work. Before using scrollIntoView I used `<a>` tags in the NavItem, but also didn't work.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be nice if you share any code to fully understand the behaviour.

Comment: hey @filoscoder,  thanks for your reply, I added some code in the question.